# Checking First Character of a String with Blade Template

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-blade

Right now, in my controller, I'm passing some alphabetized data to my explore view.

```
public function browse()
{
    return View::make('explore')
    ->with('artists', Artist::orderBy('artist', 'ASC')->get());


}
```

And then in the view, I'm using Blade to loop through that information.

```
<ul>
            @foreach($artists as $artist)
            <a href="/{{ $artist->artist }}"><li>{{ $artist->artist }}</li></a>
            @endforeach
</ul>
```

I want to run a conditional that checks the first letter of each artist so I can further group the data under the correct starting letter. How would you do that with Blade? I saw the helper "starts_with" but I'm not quite sure how to implement that into a conditional.

Answer (score 2):

This logic really belongs somewhere other than the view/template layer.  A View Composer could be a better location, or perhaps even a model method to return your data separated by starting letter - thus returning a hash of arrays containing artists under each letter.

Example code:

```
class Artist extends Eloquent
{
  public static function allByFirstCharacter()
  {
    $artists = Artist::orderBy('artist', 'ASC')->get();

    return $artists->reduce(function($sortedArtists, $artist) {
        $firstChar = $artist->artist[0];

        if (!isset($sortedArtists[$firstChar])) {
            $sortedArtists[$firstChar] = [];
        }

        $sortedArtists[$firstChar][] = $artist;

        return $sortedArtists;
    }, []);
  }
}

// Controller
$sortedArtists = Artist::allByFirstCharacter(); // Then pass it to the view

// In view

@foreach ($sortedArtists as $letter => $artists)
    <!-- Some menu item or something similar here -->
    @foreach ($artist as $artist)
        <!-- Print out details of artist -->
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Note that this example only fills in existing first characters.  If you'd like to have all characters in the alphabet/numbers you'd need to prepopulate the hash and then reduce it.